# ProductCatalogOutputConfig returning zero results

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

When i try to do base line index it is getting success  but ProductCatalogOutputConfig returining zero results. I am using 11.2 version.

I have verified my switching datas and site ids for all(catalog,category,products,skus). all are being properly associated. even i able to generate the test data from ProductCatalogOutputConfig compononent in dyn/admin.

```
PreIndexing (Duration: 0:00:00)
 /atg/commerce/endeca/index/CategoryTreeService  COMPLETE (Succeeded) RepositoryExport (Duration: 0:00:11)
 /atg/commerce/endeca/index/SchemaExporter     *79*     0     COMPLETE (Succeeded)
 /atg/commerce/endeca/index/CategoryToDimensionOutputConfig     *18*     0     COMPLETE (Succeeded)
 /atg/commerce/endeca/index/RepositoryTypeDimensionExporter     *15*     0     COMPLETE (Succeeded)
 /atg/commerce/search/ProductCatalogOutputConfig      *0*     0     COMPLETE (Succeeded)
```

EndecaIndexing (Duration: 0:00:37)
     /atg/commerce/endeca/index/EndecaScriptService               COMPLETE (Succeeded)

I have enabled debug for bulk load component and noticed one error like in the below

```
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691248   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   itemDescriptor: [ItemDesc: product] 
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691249   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   repositoryView: atg.adapter.gsa.GSAView@21be285c
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691250   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   client calling take() with 0 items in item queue
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691250   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ProcessRanges() calling take() with 0 items in range queue
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691259   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   Got: 4
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691259   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   batchCount:20,000, startIndex:0, endIndex:20,000
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691266   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ii=0, lastItem=null, query options=range 0-20000<sortby>
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691266   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader     <sortbyvalue value="id" dir=ascending case sensitive>
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691266   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   </sortby>
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691275   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ids == [], size=0
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691277   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   createIdRanges() thread is done
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691277   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ProcessRanges() took range: IdRange{firstItem:null, lastItem:null, inclusive?: false, terminal?:true}
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691280   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   Put: 4
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691280   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   First page returned 4 items.
 debug  Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691281   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ProcessRanges() calling take() with 1 items in range queue
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691283   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   ProcessRanges() took range: IdRange{firstItem:null, lastItem:null, inclusive?: false, terminal?:true}
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691285   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   processRanges() thread is done
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691288   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   processRanges() thread is done
 debug  Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691289   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   Interrupting taker thread: Thread[Thread-90,5,Pooled Threads]
 debug  Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader   Interrupted fetching via ThreadedItemQueue  java.lang.InterruptedException
 debug  Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.ThreadedItemQueue.take(ThreadedItemQueue.java:383)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.BulkLoaderImpl.fetchItemsUsingThreadedQueue(BulkLoaderImpl.java:530)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.BulkLoaderImpl.loadPagedIteration(BulkLoaderImpl.java:599)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.BulkLoaderImpl.bulkLoad(BulkLoaderImpl.java:997)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.IndexingOutputConfig.bulkLoad(IndexingOutputConfig.java:1771)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.repository.search.indexing.IndexingOutputConfig.bulkLoadForDiagnostics(IndexingOutputConfig.java:1715)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.endeca.index.EndecaIndexingOutputConfig.performBaselineUpdate(EndecaIndexingOutputConfig.java:1197)
 debug  Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingTask.doTask(IndexingTask.java:445)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingTask.performTask(IndexingTask.java:388)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.endeca.index.admin.IndexingPhase$IndexingTaskJob.invoke(IndexingPhase.java:501)
debug   Tue Jul 19 19:11:31 +05:30 2016 1468935691290   /atg/search/repository/BulkLoader       at atg.common.util.ThreadDispatcherThread.run(ThreadDispatcherThread.java:178)
```

Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: Did you run Catalog Maintenance Service?

Comment: Yes I ran and checked.. but no positive..

Comment: What is the [transaction timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55783_01/Platform.11-2/ATGEndecaIntegrationGuide/html/s0107increasingthetransactiontimeout01.html) on jdbc connection?  This is often the problem as the default value is pretty low and might mean the transaction is timing out before the load completes.